# Is there a way of combining these 2 MySQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I would like to run a query that adds 1 to the `qa_votes` field, and then retrieves the resulting value of that field so I can show it on the front end.

So the code draft would be

```
    $this->db->query("
    UPDATE  qa
    SET     qa_votes = qa_votes +1
    WHERE   qa_id = $question_id;
    ");
```

followed by

```
    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT  qa_id, qa_votes
    FROM    qa
    WHERE   qa_id = $question_id;
    ");
```

Is there a way of combining these 2 into a single query?

Comment: Could you use a stored function on the database? I guess it depends on language/database type.

Comment: Well, no, they are two separate commands. Are you asking whether you can do this using only a single command from your client library? The answer to this is most likely yes.

Comment: well I'd like to know if there is legal syntax that would allow an update followed by select of the same field so I can access the updated value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: Not with an out-of-the-box command. [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) command does not provide that. You could, however, write a [Stored Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) that updates and then brings back the result.

Comment: makes sense, just wanted to make sure if both could be done in a single DB hit

Comment: BTW, have you tried @Dems' answer? I'm not sure that works, but if it does, it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next value to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID()

So you can do something like:

```
$this->db->query("
UPDATE  qa
SET     qa_votes = LAST_INSERT_ID(qa_votes +1)
WHERE   qa_id = $question_id;
");
```

Followed by

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
```

The MySQL API that you use may have a shortcut for retrieving the last (e.g. mysql_insert_id() in PHP).

Comment: But as far as I see you still need a query to get the value of LAST_INSERT_ID(). Could  you provide an example?

Comment: i understand - so there is no way of doing a single query to get both actions

Comment: @sagi: Perhaps `SET     qa_votes = LAST_INSERT_ID(qa_votes +1)`?

Comment: The second query is not really another query, it just retrieves a variable stored in the MySQL session, and therefore returns immediately. It is equal to retrieving an automatically incremented ID value after inserting a new record to the database.

Comment: torr: if you use mysql_insert_id(), then I think it really is just a single query and there's no second round-trip to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them both into a single SQL string?

```
 $query = $this->db->query("
    UPDATE  qa
    SET     qa_votes = qa_votes +1
    WHERE   qa_id = $question_id;

    SELECT  qa_id, qa_votes
    FROM    qa
    WHERE   qa_id = $question_id;
    ");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest. I am curious to see if this works.